# Dijkstras multiple copies of cells in the heap

Tags: dijkstra

I am trying to do a Dijkstra's shortest path on a grid. Right now I have it working, but I do have some confusion. Say I am looking at a cell in the grid, I evaluate it and then push all of its neighbors into the heap if they are not evaluated. The issue I run into is I end up with multiple instances of the same cell in the heap which really bogs down the process. To fix this, I set it to not push a cell onto the heap if its already in the heap. Is this a correct approach, or could this lead to issues? This is over an unweighted grid.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a dijkstra, you don't have a heap, you have a *priority queue*.
And you have to store the shortest distance you arrived to the node at. So if you arrive again, but with a higher distance, you basically ignore the arrival. If with a shorter distance, you have to update the node's priority in the queue accordingly instead of inserting it twice ( if your queue's implementation doesn't support priority change, then you just remove the node and reinsert it with new priority )

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: Isn't a priority queue implemented w/ a minHeap?

Comment: Dijkstra does not prescribe any particular implementation. Choose one you have at hand. ( most probably already in one of the standard libraries of the language you are using )